# Flutter unresolved package in Android Manifest com.apptreesoftware.barcodescan

Tags: dart, flutter, barcode

I'm trying to set up a QR code scanner in my app following directions online, but for some reason when i add 
`<activity android:name="com.apptreesoftware.barcodescan.BarcodeScannerActivity"/>`
it gives me unresolved package error. Not sure why since i added `barcode_scan ^0.0.4` to my yaml file.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a colon in `barcode_scan ^0.0.4`. It should be `barcode_scan: ^0.0.4`.